# Need some help for this C code

Tags: c

I have even entered value even between 3 to 10 but same error. Need some help!

```
int main() {
    printf("\nPlease enter the number of days between 3 and 10, inclusive:\n");

    int high[10] = { 0 };
    int low[3] = { 0 };

    int i = 0;
    int days = 4;

    for (i = 0; i < days; i++) {

        do
        {
            if (i < 3 || i > 10) {
              printf("Invalid entry, please enter a number between 3 and 10, inclusive:");
            }
            printf(" \nDay %d - High: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &high[i]);
            printf("Day %d - Low: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &low[i]);
       } while (i < 3 || i > 10);
    }
```

**Output Should be like this:**

(Part A)

- Day 1 - High: **6**
- Day 1 - Low: **-2**
- Day 2 - High: **8**
- Day 2 - Low: **-1**
- Day 3 - High: **7**
- Day 3 - Low: **-3**
- Day 4 - High: **9**
- Day 4 - Low: **-4**

**Other part of output:**
(Part B)

Enter a number between 1 and 4 to see the average temperature for the entered number of days, enter a negative number to exit: 5

Invalid entry, please enter a number between 1 and 4, inclusive: 3

The average temperature up to day 3 is: 2.50

Enter a number between 1 and 4 to see the average temperature for the entered number of days, enter a negative number to exit: 2

The average temperature up to day 2 is: 2.75

Enter a number between 1 and 4 to see the average temperature for the entered number of days, enter a negative number to exit: -1

Comment: And whats the error??

Comment: Any number I enter it displays "Invalid entry, please enter a number between 3 and 10, inclusive:" this line

Comment: You should [properly format your code](http://prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Using proper formatting attracts people to your question and encourages them to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens (read in the comments):

```
// THE CODE STARTS SHOWING THIS:
printf("\nPlease enter the number of days between 3 and 10, inclusive:\n");

// ...declarations...

// THEN THIS IS A DO ... WHILE, IT WILL RUN THE FIRST TIME WITHOUT CHEKING
// YOU HAVEN'T TAKEN USER INPUT YET
for (i = 0; i < days; i++) {
    // ON THE FIRST ITERATION i = 0
    do
    {
        // YOU HAVEN'T TAKEN USER INPUT YET
        // REMBEMBER THAT i = 0, SO i < 3 IS true
        if (i < 3 || i > 10) {
          // IT WILL SHOW THIS, BUT YOU HAVEN'T TAKEN USER INPUT YET
          printf("Invalid entry, please enter a number between 3 and 10, inclusive:");
        }
        // ... NOW YOU TAKE USER INPUT ...
    } while (i < 3 || i > 10);
}
```

---

I want to point out that the for loop you have will go from 0 to 3, but your `low` array only has 3 items since you declare it `int low[3]`, these items are `low[0]`, `low[1]` and `low[2]`. That means that the line `scanf("%d", &low[i]);` will point beyond the `low` array when `i` is greater than 2.

---

I'm unsure what you want, yet, here is some code to control the range of a variable:

```
int var;

do
{
    printf("\nEnter a value between 5 and 12:");
    scanf("%d", &var);
} while (var < 5 || var > 12);
```

[Run Online](https://repl.it/Fjzd/0)

Here is a variant to show a message only when the input is incorrect:

```
int var;

for(;;)
{
    printf("\nEnter a value between 5 and 12:");
    scanf("%d", &var);
    if (var < 5 || var > 12)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid Input\n");
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

[Run Online](https://repl.it/Fjzd/1)

I'd suggest to go line by line to understand how the code above works. In particular `for(;;)` will breate an infinite loop, the code will only leave it when it reaches `break;`. Note: you may also use `continue;` to skip to the next iteration of the loop, this is not used in the code above, but may come handy.

Comment: Thank You so much for your reply and help. and I understood your point there. this is what I am trying to do:

"1- If the user does not enter a value in the correct range, print the following error message:
Invalid entry, please enter a number between 3 and 10, inclusive:
Keep doing this until a valid number is input by the user.

2-Using a for loop, prompt the user to enter the high and low temperature until data is entered for the required
number of days, store the values entered in matching arrays:

Comment: @J.Dope I have extended the answer to show how to output a message on invalid input. You already know how to nest loops, you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate @Theraot